# Issue while mapping my json to model fields attribute value set 0

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

while mapping json with my object, my attribute set default value to zero, here is  my field attribute
in my ModelDTO

```
private int  ExcessRqstType;

public int getExcessRqstType() {
        return ExcessRqstType;
    }

public void setExcessRqstType(int excessRqstType) {
        ExcessRqstType = excessRqstType;
    }
```

Here is my json

```
{
"ExcessRqstType": 2,
"balance": 100000,
"ExcessFor": 1020
}
```

In output it gives me '0'

```
System.out.println(objModel.getExcessRqstType());
```

"ExcessRqstType" value in my json is '2' but when it mapped i get '0'.
I am stuck in this issue.

Comment: Share your code snip of DTO to model conversion code

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolve, this issue because of case sensitivity, I change "ExcessRqstType" to "excessRqstType" in my DTO as well as in model, also changed in json request object

```
private int  excessRqstType;

public int getExcessRqstType() {
        return excessRqstType;
    }

public void setExcessRqstType(int excessRqstType) {
        excessRqstType = excessRqstType;
    }
```